# How to merge multiple rows in report?

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

I wanted to merge multiple rows in *JasperReports*'s report without using crosstab. Is it achievable?

Here I have pasted my  jrxml code for removing duplicate printing, but it keep lines around the cell although there is no record inside.

```xml
    <textField pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="110" height="21" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DEPARTURE_DATE}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```